# Undefined method when I loop to display a f.select in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, loops

I would like to have a list in my form with all my project statuses.

The field status exist in the database. When I run something like `Project.first.status` it works fine but it doesn't when I loop into it.

When I run the following code I get :

> undefined method `statuses' for Class...

**new_form**

```
<%= form_for [@context, @project], validate: true do |f| %>
       <%= f.label "status" %>
       <%= f.select(:status, Project.statuses.keys.map{ |status| [I18n.t("#{status}"), status] %>
```

**SCHEMA**

```
create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "status"
end
```

Comment: And why do you think `Project.statuses` will work? What do you really want to do?

Comment: I have 3 different statuses. I would like my user to be able to choose between this fourth

Comment: Can you post the Project model statuses class method

Comment: There is no method statuses in my model. Status is just the name of the field in my table. And  for each instance I'd like to get only the status and display all of those in a select form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an assosciation directly on a Class so `Project.statuses` is wrong.

**`use select on Class and then map them`**

**`Project.select(:status).map(&:status).uniq`**

```
<%= form_for [@context, @project], validate: true do |f| %>
       <%= f.label "status" %>
       <%= f.select(:status, Project.select(:status).map{ |status| [I18n.t("#{status}"), status]}.uniq %>
```

Comment: @Orsay, try this.

Comment: Actually I want to display all the statuses already save in my Project table. So for each instance get only the status and display all of those in a select form. As the user can choose an existing status

Comment: use,`Project.select(:status).map(&:status).uniq`, this shld work

Comment: Cool it seems to work ! Do you know how can I add my I18n variable on your solution please ? because it do not display as I want and I don't know how to customize the displaying of your solution.

Comment: First of all, it would be more efficient to use `Project.pluck(:status).uniq`. Secondly, I don't know what OP expects `statuses.keys` to return, but it *looks like* they actually have a hash defined somewhere with a list of all statuses - seeing as they have some `I18n` translations set up for them... I'm still a bit confused what is being expected here, but having the statuses defined in a constant somewhere is more logical than re-reading them from the DB!

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I expected :)

Answer (score 1):

Use pluck to get all statuses

```
<%= f.select(:status, Project.pluck(:status).uniq.map{ |status| [I18n.t("#{status}"), status] %>
```

As per [Tom Lord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1954610/tom-lord)'s comment you can use constant for the statuses instead of reading the values from db each time you render the view.

```
PROJECT_STATUSES = ['open', 'closed', 'pending']

# And use it in view
<%= f.select(:status, PROJECT_STATUSES.map{ |status| [I18n.t("#{status}"), status] %>
```